# Explicit conversion of IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>

Tags: c#, linq, join

I have a method that performs an unmatched query on two DataTable's using LINQ. It's generating an error that through looking around online I've identified where I think the error is happening, but I can't figure out how to fix it.

```
public IEnumerable<int> UnbilledAuditKeys(DataTable audits, string keyFieldName) {
    var billedAudits =
        from x in this.GetBilledAudits().AsEnumerable()
        select new {
            k = x.Field<int>(keyFieldName)
        };

    var allAudits =
        from x in audits.AsEnumerable()
        select new {
            k = x.Field<int>(keyFieldName)
        };

    var unbilled =
        from a in allAudits
        join b in billedAudits on a.k equals b.k
            into combined
        from c in combined.DefaultIfEmpty()
        where c == null
        select new { // This is what's causing the error (I think)
            k = a.k
        };

    return unbilled; // This line the compiler is rejecting
}
```

The error returned is

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

I'm at a loss of how to fix it. I've tried the obvious like casting the whole LINQ expression to IEnumerable, but that generates a run-time exception.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

The final method:

```
public IEnumerable<int> UnbilledAuditKeys(DataTable rosliAudits, string keyFieldName) {
    var billed = this.GetBilledAudits().AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<int>(keyFieldName));
    var allaudits = rosliAudits.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<int>(keyFieldName));
    var unbilled = allaudits.Except(billed);
    return unbilled;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple fix:

```
var unbilled =
    from a in allAudits
    join b in billedAudits on a.k equals b.k
        into combined
    from c in combined.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where c == null
    select a.k;
```

Also, the other two queries don't seem to require anonymous structures and the final one can be hugely simplified:

```
public IEnumerable<int> UnbilledAuditKeys(DataTable audits, string keyFieldName) {
    var billedAudits =
        from x in this.GetBilledAudits().AsEnumerable()
        select x.Field<int>(keyFieldName);

    var allAudits =
        from x in audits.AsEnumerable()
        select x.Field<int>(keyFieldName);

    var unbilled = allAudits.Except(billedAudits); // LINQ has many useful methods like this

    return unbilled;
}
```

Comment: I LOVE LINQ!!! But I'm so new to it that I'm still treating it like SQL. Thank you so much! This worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 2):

Select your field directly instead of creating new anonymous type:

```
var unbilled =
    from a in allAudits
    join b in billedAudits on a.k equals b.k
        into combined
    from c in combined.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where c == null
    select a.k;
```